# difference between del() and flushAll() of jedis

Tags: redis, jedis

I am new to jedis. I am not able to distinguish del() and flushAll(). Does del() deletes the keys from cache or from database. Kindly provide some details. 
Please note, I did try to search for an answer on the web, but could't fine my answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Kindly read the documentation. http://redis.io/commands/del, http://redis.io/commands/flushall

Comment: @Sergio: yes, I had. So del() deletes from memory or from the database (disk)?

Comment: Redis is an in-memory database. Everything operates on memory

Comment: @Sergio: I think I got you. del() deletes specific keys, whereas flushAll() deletes everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DEL**: Deletes a single key

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> SET foo bar
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> SET XXX YYY
OK
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> keys *
1) "XXX"
2) "foo"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> DEL foo
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> keys *
1) "XXX"
```

**FLUSHALL** Redis has 12 Database by default you can choose a database by SELECT command

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379[1]> SELECT 11
```

**IMPORTANT TO REMEMBER IF YOU USE FLUSHALL COMMAND IT WILL DELETE DATA FROM ALL 12 DATABASES**

**FLUSHDB**: Deletes all keys from **CURRENT** database. May be you would like to use it in 90% of cases instead of FLUSHALL